# Installing Moodle: It is requesting 5000 under Max_input_vars

Tags: php, mamp, moodle

I cannot find the `php.ini` file or `.htaccess` file where I'm meant to change the `max_input_vars` to 5000 in my moodle website folder. I'm using mamp and myphpadmin

Moodle explains

> "To change max_input_vars you can either set it in php.ini or modify
> it in runtime, for example for Apache you can create .htaccess file:
> php_value max_input_vars 5000"

I searched in finder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test php file in the root of the Moodle folder with

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

Then open it from the browser, not the command line (the command line and web server might use different versions of php)

eg: yourmoodlesite/test.php

This will display the location of the php.ini file that is being used, eg:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
```

I haven't used MAMP, but the documentation says the php file can also be edited via the menu in MAMP PRO

File > Open Template > PHP > [PHP version] -> php.ini

It also says the location is

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf
```

https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Menu/

Answer (score 0):

This helped on Fedora, tried it on mac too

```
php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

After updating `php.ini`

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

I had to restart both

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```